# For Python 3.4: Why do I get a KeyError when I subclass defaultdict, override __init__, and define default_factory in the subclass’s scope?

Tags: python, python-3.4, defaultdict

The following code does not raise a KeyError.

```
from collections import defaultdict


class A(defaultdict):

    def __init__(self):
        self.default_factory = int


a = A()
print(a[42])  # out: 0
```

The following code raises a KeyError.

```
from collections import defaultdict


class A(defaultdict):

    def __init__(self):
        pass


class B(A):

    default_factory = int


b = B()
print(a[42])  # out: KeyError: 42
```

In my flawed imagination, the second example plays out like this:

1) call the parent `A` class's `__init__` method at the construction of the `b` object

2) call the `defaultdict` class's `__missing__` method at reference to non-existent key `42`

3) refer to the `b` object's `default_factory` attribute only to find no such attribute

4) refer to the `B` class's attributes to find `default_factory` defined as `int`

5) return `int` back to the `defaultdict` class's `__missing__` method

6) call `default_factory` (which is `int`) which returns a `0` by default to `__missing__`

7) define the `b` object's key `42` value as `0`

8) print `0`

Maybe I'm wrong about step 2? Which of my assumptions are incorrect or what is the critical difference between my first and second examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaultdict` is not a Python class, it is a *C type*. As such it doesn't support attribute lookups on the class, it only supports setting the `default_factory` on the instance.

In other words, step 4 never takes place.

Step 2 *does* take place, but this step is implemented in C as using:

```
PyObject *factory = dd->default_factory;
```

and `default_factory` is defined as a member of the instance only. See the [`defaultdict` C source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bf1b0afe419b/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#l1481).

Comment: That surprises me. I have taken it for granted that wherever Class.attribute worked self.attribute would also work. (Incidentally, I have only asked four questions on stack overflow and I believe now two of them have been answered by you!) Thanks for demystifying.